# How many ways can the letters of the word $XQRZX$ be arranged?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can the letters of the word $XQRZX$ be arranged?

This is taken from the book on Combinatorics, by Daniel Marcus. The answer given is $\frac{5!}2=60$. But, am getting different answer.

I know by rote that for repeated characters the no. of arrangements are divided by no. of repetitions of each type, i.e. for a word of $n$ characters, s.t. $n \geq mk$ characters (where, $m$ characters are repeated $k$ times), then arrangements are: $\frac{n!}{m.k!}$. Similarly, for $m$ characters being repeated $k_1,\cdots, k_m$ times; leads to arrangements as: $\frac{n!}{k_1!\cdots k_m!}$.

My logical reasoning is that for each set of repeated characters, the total no. of arrangements are divided by the lost arrangements of the repeated ones.

But, if try to have an alternative to the above logic, for the given word, then falter as below:

Considering the two $X$ distinct, leading to $5!$ chances, and subtract from that the chance of taking the arrangements of two $X$.

Divide into two cases:

Case(a): Take two as a block, with ordering not important in that block. This leads to $4!=24$ cases.

 This leaves us with $5!= 120 - 24= 96$ cases.

Case (b): The left cases (to be subtracted) come
from the other positions that two $X$ can take, apart from being placed next to each other. There are five such ways to place $X$ seperately.

$X\_---=3$ choices $\times 2=6$, 
 $\_X\_--=2$ choices $\times 2=4$,
 $-\_X\_-= 1\implies 11$ choices for placing the two $X$ seperately, but in each case the three left spaces can be filled with $3\times 2\times 1= 3!$ ways.
So, get $11\times 3!= 66$ ways. 
The last case ($-\_X\_-$) has one choice (instead of two), due to clash in one choice with the first case ( $X\_---$) .

But, seems to match need subtract $36$ cases rather than $66$ in Case (b), i.e. $96-36 =60$.

Comment: I do not understand your attempt.  You get $5!=120$ outcomes if the $X$'s were distinct.  I follow that.  So then, case (a) you are counting how many ways you could have both $X$'s together noting that you counted each of those twice but only needed to count them once?  And then in the remaining case, case (b) you are counting how many ways you could have the $X$'s separate again noting that you counted these twice when you should have counted them once?  Why not do as suggested by the book's author and divide by two since both cases were overcounted the same amount?

Comment: As for what you calculated during case (b)'s analysis... you multiplied by two for the first two subcases but not for the third?  I'm failing to see what this multiplication by two was even for... but surely there is something fishy about this since you didn't treat the subcases the same.  Remove the erroneous multiplication by two to get $3+2+1=6$ choices, not $11$, for how the $X$'s could have been placed separately giving $6\times 3!=36$ duplicate outcomes to be removed from the overall count, exactly as predicted.

Comment: If you disliked the "division by symmetry" argument, that's perfectly fine.  I tend to avoid division by symmetry arguments as a matter of principle.  An alternate explanation of the count is:  Choose the position of the $Q$.  Choose the position of the $R$.  Choose the position of the $Z$.  The remaining positions are then both occupied by $X$'s.  There are then $5\times 4\times 3 = 60$ total results.  No division necessary.  And no awkward breaking into cases either.

Comment: @JMoravitz I feel your analysis is correct, but was confused in taking the symmetric placement of the first $X$ in each case. I see it is wrong, as the second $X$ being indistinguishable, hence it's arrangements take the symmetric case automatically.

Comment: @JMoravitz Your logic for the alternative approach is quite easy. Please vet my last comment.

Comment: Note, the $\dfrac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_m!}$ can be explained as "Choose where the 1's go, then choose where the 2's go, ... , Choose where the $m$'s go" giving $\binom{n}{k_1}\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}\binom{n-k_1-k_2}{k_3}\cdots \binom{n-k_1-\dots-k_{m-1}}{k_m}$ which simplifies to the stated formula.  This of course gives the same result regardless which order you were to take the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following your logic. Say they are $X$ and $Y$ for argument sake -

Case(a): $XY$ together leads to $2 \times 4! = 48$ cases. If they are not distinct, they cannot be permuted within and so you need to subtract $24$ times.

Case (b):

$X \_  − − - \,$ has $3$ choices for $Y$ and so does $Y_ − − − -$ has $3$ choices for $X$ (total of $6$). If they are same, you overcounted $3 \times 3!$ times.

Similarly in $ \_ X \_ − − \,$  you overcount $2 \times 3!$ times.

$− \_ X \_ − $ has only one place of choice for $Y$ and similarly for $− \_ Y \_ − $, there is one choice for $X$. If they are same, you overcounted $1 \times 3!$ times.

If you add them up, you get $36$ cases you need to subtract from $(b)$.

So it is $ 120 - 36 - 24 = 60$.

Comment: Very nice. Seems my logic for case (b) is flawed, but hope the flaw lies in symmetrically considering both $X\_---, ---\_Y$ as in first subcase for Case (b) .  I mean (in the first subcase) the symmetric case ( $---\_Y$) is automatically there , once the original case $(X\_---$) is there.

Comment: If you take your first subcase in 1(b), you counted $3$ places for $X$ and $X$, and then multiplied by $2$. But first $3$ times need to be counted anyway. It is the last $3$ which are exact replica of first $3$. The same goes for second subcase. In fact even the last subset also has symmetry it is $1 \times 2$ but there you counted extra cases correctly and not doubled it.

Comment: Have an unusual request regarding setting up simulation for creating network with all non-collinear points. I have doubts in post at: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/95477/78009, and have stated my doubts in the answer there. It is difficult to frame a seperate post based on my doubts in SO, as read such post the first time. Will be quite thankful for any directions provided.